# Access denied for user 'user_name'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in java

Tags: java, jdbc

I have installed MYSQL DataBase in my machine, and have java code to manipulate the data.

Database credentials... 
Database Name:ram
username: "user_name" 
password : "123".
host is: localhost;

I gave ALL PRIVILEGES to this "user_name" user (like create, update,delete nd etc..)

Now i want to connect with Database we use the following method

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:MySql://localhost/ram","user_name","123");
```

Well its working correctly.

Now i changed the user credentials as
Host: 127.0.0.1

and replace the connection syntax as `DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:MySql://127.0.0.1/ram","Ramesh","123");`

Good,, its working fine ..
Now i want to connect to DB with any host for this user.
so i change the user details as 
Host:%

used the following method to connect with DB

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:MySql://127.0.0.1/ram","Ramesh","123");
```

but it gives an error like

```
Access denied for user 'Ramesh'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I can't decide  this problem which belongs to either java code or DB code.

Please let me out from this one guys...Thanks in advnce...

Comment: Did you include MySQL JAR driver in your code?

Comment: Can this help:http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?11,34014,46593 ?

Comment: What does "Now i want to connect to DB with any host for this user" mean?

Comment: How have you changed the privileges?

Comment: ya Sam,,
MySQL JAR file is in my lib folder,,,

Comment: am using XAMP (MYSQl,Apache ), software and all changes of privileges are make over here(localhost/phpmyadmin )

Answer (score 1):

you need do `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` after you changes to `%` to make those changes take affect

Comment: am using xamp server(included mysql, Apache), So changes are saved automatically,, but still i got the same error again and again..Aviram..

Comment: before trying to connect from java, did you connect with any other client (sqlyog, etc.) after this change? if you can connect from another client, then you should focus on java, if not, solve the db issue first.

Comment: how can i connect with another client into mysql (Localhost), could you please elaborate it Aviram ,,,